# chrome remote desktop 56 shows black screen in ubuntu14.04

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, remote

I got Google Chrome Black Screen in Ubuntu 14.04 today.
the version of Chrome remote desktop is 56.0.29

I know there is a solution: [Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04)

But I cannot find `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/` in my system.
There is no `chrome-remote-desktop` folder under `/opt/google/`
I searched, no result...

Maybe the new Chrome(56) have made some change in Ubuntu? Why didn't they fix this long history problem but made it unfix-able now:)

Comment: Thx for edit it. Sorry... my fault... this happens because my remote PC win10 black screen itself, not the ubuntu chrome. i fixed my win10 PC last night, it works fine now. Chrome is cool.